# Python Bokeh - Making example standalone - Widget error

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm learning Bokeh, I would like to make the example 'stocks' script  https://demo.bokeh.org/stocks produce a standalone html file...I have added the following code:

```
from bokeh.embed import components

plots = [corr, ts1, ts2]
script, div = components(plots)
print(script)
print(div)


html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.css"   type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.js"></script>

        <!-- COPY/PASTE SCRIPT HERE -->
        {}

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- INSERT DIVS HERE -->
        {}
    </body>
</html>""".format(script, div)

with open("plotstock.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

at the bottom of the script, and this worked for a simpler example found at http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html (which has no widget imports) but for the stock script I get errors:

> **Bokeh Error**
>
> Model `PreText' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage.**

If I remove reference to this widget, I get the same error for the next widget in line, the Select widget...

I can run this script ok in the bokeh server with the data localised, but the embedding is the issue...

The generated html does seem complete, with the data and components sections:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.css"   type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.6.min.js"></script>

        <!-- COPY/PASTE SCRIPT HERE -->
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
  var fn = function() {
    Bokeh.safely(function() {
      var docs_json = {"15b39cbd-8b49-4761-9152-f666c6fb1d9a":{"roots": {"references":[{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"f6f697cf-6d00-4218-94c1- 18c7e97d7e16","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"3764347f-7617-42a8-a1d4- 0a6b255fc47d","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_    glyph":{"id":"461527a6-e0fe-4159-89a8- c748b3f16335","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null},"id":"a6991b17-5e11-4864- 92ed-85b29f7fe737","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"months": [0,4,8]},"id":"a3ac5382-f490-408f-b608-f3cdca26772b","type":"MonthsTicker"},    {"attr   ....  ["87c565c2-e8d1-41ea-958d-ea09daa88b3a"]},"title":"Stocks","version":"0.12.6"}};
      var render_items = [{"docid":"15b39cbd-8b49-4761-9152-f666c6fb1d9a","elementid":"ac68790a-4571-49cb-8d1c-08c6f3a9d711","modelid":"a5ab1659-6d31-4869-8d5d-184d27fd5732"},   {"docid":"15b39cbd-8b49-4761-9152-f666c6fb1d9a","elementid":"202aa28c-793d-46df-99ed-30cc4d62b827","modelid":"c22f84ba-56d9-49ab-9d81-314546cfec5c"},  {"docid":"15b39cbd-8b49-4761-9152-f666c6fb1d9a","elementid":"725a58d5-6c34-4f56-8d82-64ebef5c4e46","modelid":"e1fc4190-8882-4d48-be12-b46f9817d525"}];
  
      Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
    });
  };
  if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
})();

</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- INSERT DIVS HERE -->
        ('\n<div class="bk-root">\n    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="ac68790a-4571-49cb-8d1c-08c6f3a9d711"></div>\n</div>', '\n<div class="bk-root">\n    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="202aa28c-793d-46df-99ed-30cc4d62b827"></div>\n</div>', '\n<div class="bk-root">\n    <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="725a58d5-6c34-4f56-8d82-64ebef5c4e46"></div>\n</div>')
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me what is happening or have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS files for Bokeh widgets are distributed separately, so that pages only incur the cost of loading them if they actually use them. You need to include `bokeh-widgets` from CDN as described [in the documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components):

```
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.6.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.6.min.js"></script>
```